# Notification center only toast notifications in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, notifications, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is it possible to create some toast notifications that are only saved to the notification center rather than also showing the top-screen banners on Windows Phone 8.1 and 10?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked [ToastNotification.SuppressPopup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotification.suppresspopup.aspx) ?